# Good DataGridView tutorial

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I'm writing a windows C# application which I wish to use data grid views, but unable to find a good tutorial on to take complete control of the datagrid eg: add columns, add data etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like some of the tips provided [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview)

Comment: Nice! There's a reference to a proper tutorial: http://dotnetperls.com/Content/DataGridView-Tutorial.aspx

Comment: The old link seems to be dead. I think this is the new one: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview

Comment: Other links are dead. This is the current link for the tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look here: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k39d6s23.aspx

But the best one might be this: http://www.macoratti.net/08/08/c_pdgv1.htm
I think you can get the idea from the code, since the comments are in portuguese (you can try google translate).

Comment: I found the MSDN reference here very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using an MVC/P pattern for implementing DataGridView in Winforms - it makes life a lot easier in the long run, even though it may seem a lot of work to do up front.

[Selecting a MVC/MVP Implementation for a Winforms Project](http://rdn-consulting.com/blog/2008/02/01/selecting-a-mvcmvp-implementation-for-a-winforms-project/)