# How to update remote MS SQL Database using dataGridView1

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, winforms

using c#/winforms, I used the designer view to add a datagridview control to the form and set it up... It can successfully read from the remote database :) but I need for it to be able to update the database too, for example, when I add new rows or edit/remove existing ones.

How can this be done?

Thanks, and any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367559/good-datagridview-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. One is to use a binding source component tied to a typed dataset or business object as datasource.

BindingSource will handle the CRUD functions between user and dataset/datatable. Use tableadapters for final updates.

[BindingSource Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h974h4y2%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Aseem! I'll check this out soon :)