# How to save the result of a MS-Access select query in variables in C#.net?

Tags: c#, ms-access

My question is simple but i don't know how to do it my query is:

```
" SELECT * FROM Table1 Where ID =" + textBox1.Text;
```

and I want to save the result in variables the table of the query has 5 columns that means i want 5 variables to save the results but I don't know how can I do this the database is in ms-Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to know, how to make an [OleDbConnection](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-oledb-connection.htm) in C#.

you don't need to create variables!. You can directly assign all your rows or the selected one to one of the many datacontrols available in ASP.NET and winforms both.

DataControls automatically show your db.table data in a tabular layout on a page or a form.
you can also control the look of this automatically created layout.

you can fetch your data from the db and create a dataset like this:

```
string query = "SELECT * from Table1 WHERE ID=?";

OleDbConnection odc = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
odc.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,odc);

cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.BSTR, 5).Value ="asdf";
dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

ds = new DataSet();
dAdapter.Fill(ds);

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

now in above code, `strConn` is the connectionString to the access db file. every kind of storage requires a unique kind of connectionstring. you can find out the one suitable for you [here](http://connectionstrings.com/).

Once you are clear with that. you need to learn about [ASP.NET DataControls](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/aspnet-data-controls) and winforms [dataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367559/good-datagridview-tutorial) and many others.

Comment: i want to save results in variables because the next step is to insert the results in a different database

Comment: so what's the problem, you have the DataSet with you, it contains all your data, you can iterate through that and save your data in another table

Comment: the other table has more columns and different structure

Comment: so what, did you notice how you can execute a Select Query in the above code. same way you can execute Insert Query. since this Insert Query is a string and you are going to create it, create it the way you want, just assign it appropriate values from the dataset

Comment: could you please give me an example because i don't understand

Comment: something like: `"insert into table2(col1,col2) values('"+ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString()+"','"+ ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString() +"')"`

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874887/using-oledbdataadapter-and-dataset-to-update-access-mdb) example on how to insert from dataset to access db